# HTML/CSS Image Navigation Bar

Tags: css, html

I'm making a navigation bar for my website. The navigation bar is a picture, and I'm wondering if in CSS you can section off parts of the image to link to different pages. Is this possible? If so, how?

The map tag suggestion worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an html MAP tag, see http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/map

Comment: Please don't refer people to w3schools. To know the reason, go to http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 2):

Two different ways to do what you want:

- An [image map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map) (doesn't really use CSS, though), or
- Use proper [HTML markup+CSS sprites](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites), something like:

  ```
  <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="foo">Foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="bar">Bar</a></li>
      <li><a href="baz">Baz</a></li>
  </ul>
  ```

and combine this with CSS [`background-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-position).

Answer (score 1):

You Should try CSS image sprites http://stylemeltdown.com/2007/10/22/image-sprite-navigation-with-css/ for your navigation. Or you could use an image map, but I think the CSS sprites are a more modern and standard way to do this.